# vpn ubuntu mac os file transfer

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, mac-osx

I have an Ubuntu Server that works on VPN, to connect to the machine I use ssh. I would like to transfer some files from my Mac box to Ubuntu server.

Can anyone explain or point where to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

`- rsync`

`- scp` (preferable)

`- filezilla`

The use of scp from Mac box:

`scp file_on_Mac_box username@ubuntubox:.`  The (dot) at the end of `ubuntubox:.` indicates that the files would be placed into the home dir of `username`